# Saving data to a text file and loading it into a datagrid in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sql-server-2005, c#-3.0

I need to Pass some data to a text file and save that text file in a SQL Server 2005 database.

Then I'll need to be able to load that textfile into a C# WinForms DataGrid.

How do I do that in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this tutorial:

[This tutorial demonstrates how to use the Xilytix  TFieldedText component  to read a CSV file and place the headings and records into a .NET WinForms DataGrid.](http://www.fieldedtext.org/Tutorials/Xilytix/C-Sharp/ReadABasicCsvFile.html)

Answer (score 2):

Why not read the data from the SQL Server into the datagrid instead of reading it from the text file?  Loading data from a database into a grid should be easy straight out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question where the data begins, or why you need the text file. However, I will answer one of your points. There are lots of ways to read a text file. This is how I usually do it:

First, write out a file with the schema

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sPath + @"\schema.ini"))

            {
                sw.WriteLine("[" + sFile + "]");
                sw.WriteLine("ColNameHeader=False");
                sw.WriteLine("Format=FixedLength");
                sw.WriteLine("Col1=CO_ID Text Width 2");
                sw.WriteLine("Col2=AGENCY_CD Text Width 10");
                // lines for additional columns here
                sw.Close();
                sw.Dispose();
            }
```

Then read the data to a DataSet using ODCB.

```
            string cs = @"Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};DBQ=" + sPath;
            OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection(cs);
            string q = @"select * from [" + sNewFN + "]";
            OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(q, cn);
            da.Fill(ds, "MyTable");
```

The table ds.Tables["MyTable"] is the DataSource for the DataGrid

There is info about this method here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714091%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Followup: Windows 7 does not support the text drive.